# How can i delete element in set Redis?

Tags: java, redis, lettuce

how can i delete element(s) from sorted set generated from adding location using GEOADD

for example:

```
GEOADD test -0.12455 51.5007 "Big Ben" -0.12520 51.50115 "Westminster Station" -0.11358 51.50482 "BFI IMAX"
```

i want to delete "Westminster Station" element , any ideas?
and is there away to delete this element using Lettuce Api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GEO index is implemented with `Sorted Set`, so you can just use `zrem` to remove a location.

```
`zrem test "Westminster Station"`
```